# onCallback React Hook - best practice query

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is more of a best practice question than anything. But I'm wondering if any inline functions within a React component should typically be wrapped with an onCallback for performance? Under what circumstances would I not wrap a function like this with onCallback?

For example:

```
const ToolSearch = (props: ToolsSearchProps) => {

 const handleOnClick = () => {
    alert('do something');
 }
  
  return (
    <NoCardOverflow>
        <ToolSearchCollapse openState={filtersOpen} onClick={handleOnClick} />
    </NoCardOverflow>
  );
};
```

In this example should I be doing this:

```
   const ToolSearch = (props: ToolsSearchProps) => {

     const handleOnClick = useCallback(() => {
        alert('do something');
     },[]);
      
      return (
        <NoCardOverflow>
            <ToolSearchCollapse openState={filtersOpen} onClick={handleOnClick} />
        </NoCardOverflow>
      );
    };
```

Comment: good read on useCallBack and useMemo https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback

Comment: since `handleOnClick` doesnt reference anything inside of component, its better to define it outside of `ToolSearch` component, that way react won't redefine `handleclick` function every time it renders.

Comment: @Hitheshk this is something deep for me, thanks, will go through this once more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain the `useCallBack` with an example. We all know the definition of `useCallBack`, but **when to use** is the trick part here. So, let me take an example.

```js
const RenderText = React.memo(({ text }) => {
  console.log(`Render ${text}`);
  return (<div>{text}</div>);
});

const App = () => {
  const [count, updateCount] = React.useState(0);
  const [lists, updateLists] = React.useState(["list 1"]);

  const addListItem = () => {
    updateLists([...lists, "random"]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {`Current Count is ${count}`}
      <button onClick={() => updateCount((prev) => prev + 1)}>Update Count</button>

      {lists.map((item: string, index: number) => (
        <RenderText key={index} text={item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/enyctuLp/1/

In the above, there are two states.

- count - Number
- lists - Array

The `RenderText` just renders the text passed to it. (which is the item in the list). If you click on the `Update Count` button, the `RenderText` will not re-render because it is independent from the main component (`App`) and during the `updateCount`, only the `App` component will re-render, since it needs to update the `count` value.

Now, pass the `addListItem` into `RenderText` component and click on the `Update Count` button and see what happens.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/enyctuLp/2/

You can see that the `RenderText` will re-render even though there is no change in the `list` array and this is **BECAUSE** :

- when the count is updated, the `App` will re-render
- which, will re-render the `addListItem`
- which causes the `RenderText` to re-render.

To avoid this, we should use `useCallBack` hook.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/enyctuLp/4/

Now, the `addListItem` function has been memoized and it will only change when the dependency are changed.

Comment: hold up, thats not how you update a state with prev value (talking about `updateCounter` ).
it suppose to be like this ```updateCount((prev_count) => prev_count + 1)```

Comment: @bogdanoff I agree with you. I was concentrating on the `useCallBack` and forgot about this. will update the answer. :)

Comment: @bogdanoff do we really need prev_count as function parameter in this particular case? shouldn't it be directly count+1

Comment: @RanuVijay both methods are correct. Most will prefer the functional parameter whiling updating the value. To answer your question, just `count+1` works

Answer (score 0):

**ToolSearchCollapse** is your child component, and so wrapping your handleClick function makes sense. Coz every time the parent component re-renders a new reference of handleclick will be passed to **ToolSearchCollapse**, and your child will re-render every time a parent state changes, (from states that aren't passed to the child also). Using **useCallback** will not allow creating new references, and thus you can control when your child should render.

If you don't pass this fn to the child, I don't see any reason to use useCallback.

Comment: when use useCallback, you have to include all variables referenced inside that callback in dependency list, which is big head ache when use large no. of variables & functions inside callback.

Comment: Yes, all the referenced data should be in dependency. But if your child is complex or fetches external data, it is worth having.